# C# Generic type casting to template parameter type fails?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, casting

I am trying to create a system where by I promote a base class to a derived class and use it as such, however if you see the error below it seems it is trying to convert a 'NodeType' to the derived type even though NodeType isn't a real type.

This does not work:

```
class Node {}
class Navpoint : Node {}
class Jumppoint : Node {}

class Actor {
  public static void on<NodeType>(Actor actor, Node node) where NodeType : Node {
     actor.Navigate(node as NodeType);  // error: (CS1502) cannot convert NodeType to Navpoint
  }

  private static IDictionary<System.Type, Navigation> navigations = 
    new Dictionary<System.Type, Navigation>() {
     {typeof(Navpoint), on<Navpoint>},
     {typeof(Jumppoint), on<Jumppoint>},
  };

  public void Navigate(Node node) {
   navigations[node.GetType()](this, node);
  }
 public void Navigate(Navpoint navpoint) {
     // do something with navpoint
  }
  public void Navigate(Jumppoint jumppoint) {
     // do something with jumppoint
 }
}
```

This however does work:

```
class Node {}
class Navpoint : Node {}
class Jumppoint : Node {}

class Actor {
  public static void onNavpoint(Actor actor, Node node) {
     actor.Navigate(node as Navpoint);  // works fine
  }
  public static void onJumppoint(Actor actor, Node node) {
     actor.Navigate(node as Jumppoint);  // works fine
  }

  private static IDictionary<System.Type, Navigation> navigations = 
    new Dictionary<System.Type, Navigation>() {
     {typeof(Navpoint), onNavpoint},
     {typeof(Jumppoint), onJumppoint},
 };

  public void Navigate(Node node) {
    navigations[node.GetType()](this, node);
  }
  public void Navigate(Navpoint navpoint) {
     // do something with navpoint
 }
  public void Navigate(Jumppoint jumppoint) {
     // do something with jumppoint
 }
}
```

Not really a big deal typing out 20 or so almost duplicate lines of code but my question is WHY?

Also I am using Unity and MonoDevelop, I don't know if .NET would handle this differently..

Comment: The code you've given compiles fine for me, having removed the body of the `Navigate(Node)` method and the dictionary (as they refer to the missing `Navigation` type).

Comment: Perhaps you have another type `NodeType` somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: Same as Jon for me.  I think @PeterRitchie is right; you have a conflict with `NodeType` somewhere.

Comment: The first example you posted works fine on this end (well, after some minor cleanup - like I'm assuming `Navigation` is `delegate void Navigation(Actor a, Node n)` - what version of .NET are you using? What platform? (you mention mono?)

Comment: I had to guess about the definition of Navigation since it wasn't included in your original post, but the line of code in question compiles fine in Visual Studio 2010.  The issue might be specific to Mono.  Consider defining a virtual NodeType property and override it in the derived classes rather than using reflection.

Comment: The code seems to compile fine, but I doubt it does what you want.  The `on<NodeType>` delegate will ALWAYS call `Navigate(Node)`, regardless of the type `NodeType` since this call will be resolved at compile time, and `NodeType` can only be guaranteed to be a `Node`.  You should see a `StackOverflowException` since `Navigate(Node)` also calls the delegate in return.